# How to pull out each slide of a powerpoint and convert them to .png

Tags: unix

I'm trying to write a C program that converts each slide of a powerpoint presentation to .png files. I have tried unoconv but the problem is that it only converts the first slide. Is there any way to iterate through the .ppt and convert each slide to a .png?

Answer (score 0):

What I have usually done is print the PPT using Windows to a virtual printer that emits to PDF or PostScript. From there, one can then convert to PNG — for example using GhostScript — if desired.